# Python - Find duplicates in a list of dictionaries and group them

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary

i'm not a programmer and also new to python, i have a list of dicts coming from a json file:

```
# JSON file (film.json)
[{"year": ["1999"], "director": ["Wachowski"], "film": ["The Matrix"], "price": ["19,00"]},
{"year": ["1994"], "director": ["Tarantino"], "film": ["Pulp Fiction"], "price": ["20,00"]},
{"year": ["2003"], "director": ["Tarantino"], "film": ["Kill Bill vol.1"], "price": ["10,00"]},
{"year": ["2003"], "director": ["Wachowski"], "film": ["The Matrix Reloaded"], "price": ["9,99"]},
{"year": ["1994"], "director": ["Tarantino"], "film": ["Pulp Fyction"], "price": ["15,00"]},
{"year": ["1994"], "director": ["E. de Souza"], "film": ["Street Fighter"], "price": ["2,00"]},
{"year": ["1999"], "director": ["Wachowski"], "film": ["The Matrix"], "price": ["20,00"]},
{"year": ["1982"], "director": ["Ridley Scott"], "film": ["Blade Runner"], "price": ["19,99"]}]
```

i can import json file with:

```
import json
json_file = open('film.json')
f = json.load(json_file)
```

but after that i'm not able to find occurrences in `f` and separate them in groups by film title.
This is what i'm looking for to achieve:

```
## result grouped by 'film'
#group 1
{"year": ["1999"], "director": ["Wachowski"], "film": ["The Matrix"], "price": ["19,00"]}
{"year": ["1999"], "director": ["Wachowski"], "film": ["The Matrix"], "price": ["20,00"]}
#group 2
{"year": ["1994"], "director": ["Tarantino"], "film": ["Pulp Fiction"], "price": ["20,00"]}
{"year": ["1994"], "director": ["Tarantino"], "film": ["Pulp Fyction"], "price": ["15,00"]}
#group X
 ...
```

Or better:

```
new_dict = { 'group1':[[],[],...] , 'group2':[[],[],...] , 'groupX':[...] }
```

At the moment i'm testing with nested `for` but without luck..

Thank you.

note: "pulp fyction" is a wanted mistake for future implementation with fuzzy string matching, for now i need only a 'duplicates grouper'

note2: with python 2.x

Comment: What are you grouping on?  Title alone?  Title + director + year?

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby

Comment: Why not name your groups by film?

Comment: @wim grouping the whole dict line (title,director,year,price) based on values in 'film' key. So yes, title alone.

Answer (score 9):

Because your data is not sorted, use a [`collections.defaultdict()` object](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to materialize a list for new keys, then key by film title:

```
from collections import defaultdict

grouped = defaultdict(list)

for film in f:
    grouped[film['film'][0]].append(film)
```

The `film['film'][0]` value is used to group the films. You would have to create a canonical version of that key if you wanted to use more sophisticated title grouping.

Demo:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> import json
>>> with open('film.json') as film_file:
...     f = json.load(film_file)
... 
>>> grouped = defaultdict(list)
>>> for film in f:
...     grouped[film['film'][0]].append(film)
... 
>>> grouped
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {u'Street Fighter': [{u'director': [u'E. de Souza'], u'price': [u'2,00'], u'film': [u'Street Fighter'], u'year': [u'1994']}], u'Pulp Fiction': [{u'director': [u'Tarantino'], u'price': [u'20,00'], u'film': [u'Pulp Fiction'], u'year': [u'1994']}], u'Pulp Fyction': [{u'director': [u'Tarantino'], u'price': [u'15,00'], u'film': [u'Pulp Fyction'], u'year': [u'1994']}], u'The Matrix': [{u'director': [u'Wachowski'], u'price': [u'19,00'], u'film': [u'The Matrix'], u'year': [u'1999']}, {u'director': [u'Wachowski'], u'price': [u'20,00'], u'film': [u'The Matrix'], u'year': [u'1999']}], u'Blade Runner': [{u'director': [u'Ridley Scott'], u'price': [u'19,99'], u'film': [u'Blade Runner'], u'year': [u'1982']}], u'Kill Bill vol.1': [{u'director': [u'Tarantino'], u'price': [u'10,00'], u'film': [u'Kill Bill vol.1'], u'year': [u'2003']}], u'The Matrix Reloaded': [{u'director': [u'Wachowski'], u'price': [u'9,99'], u'film': [u'The Matrix Reloaded'], u'year': [u'2003']}]})
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(dict(grouped))
{u'Blade Runner': [{u'director': [u'Ridley Scott'],
                    u'film': [u'Blade Runner'],
                    u'price': [u'19,99'],
                    u'year': [u'1982']}],
 u'Kill Bill vol.1': [{u'director': [u'Tarantino'],
                       u'film': [u'Kill Bill vol.1'],
                       u'price': [u'10,00'],
                       u'year': [u'2003']}],
 u'Pulp Fiction': [{u'director': [u'Tarantino'],
                    u'film': [u'Pulp Fiction'],
                    u'price': [u'20,00'],
                    u'year': [u'1994']}],
 u'Pulp Fyction': [{u'director': [u'Tarantino'],
                    u'film': [u'Pulp Fyction'],
                    u'price': [u'15,00'],
                    u'year': [u'1994']}],
 u'Street Fighter': [{u'director': [u'E. de Souza'],
                      u'film': [u'Street Fighter'],
                      u'price': [u'2,00'],
                      u'year': [u'1994']}],
 u'The Matrix': [{u'director': [u'Wachowski'],
                  u'film': [u'The Matrix'],
                  u'price': [u'19,00'],
                  u'year': [u'1999']},
                 {u'director': [u'Wachowski'],
                  u'film': [u'The Matrix'],
                  u'price': [u'20,00'],
                  u'year': [u'1999']}],
 u'The Matrix Reloaded': [{u'director': [u'Wachowski'],
                           u'film': [u'The Matrix Reloaded'],
                           u'price': [u'9,99'],
                           u'year': [u'2003']}]}
```

Using [SoundEx](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundex) to group films would be as simple as:

```
from itertools import groupby, islice, ifilter

_codes = ('bfpv', 'cgjkqsxz', 'dt', 'l', 'mn', 'r')
_sounds = {c: str(i) for i, code in enumerate(_codes, 1) for c in code}
_sounds.update(dict.fromkeys('aeiouy'))
def soundex(word, _sounds=_sounds):
    grouped = groupby(_sounds[c] for c in word.lower() if c in _sounds)
    if _sounds.get(word[0].lower()):
        next(grouped)  # remove first group.
    sdx = ''.join([k for k, g in islice((g for g in grouped if g[0]), 3)])
    return word[0].upper() + format(sdx, '<03')

grouped_by_soundex = defaultdict(list)
for film in f:
    grouped_by_soundex[soundex(film['film'][0])].append(film)
```

resulting in:

```
>>> pprint(dict(grouped_by_soundex))
{u'B436': [{u'director': [u'Ridley Scott'],
            u'film': [u'Blade Runner'],
            u'price': [u'19,99'],
            u'year': [u'1982']}],
 u'K414': [{u'director': [u'Tarantino'],
            u'film': [u'Kill Bill vol.1'],
            u'price': [u'10,00'],
            u'year': [u'2003']}],
 u'P412': [{u'director': [u'Tarantino'],
            u'film': [u'Pulp Fiction'],
            u'price': [u'20,00'],
            u'year': [u'1994']},
           {u'director': [u'Tarantino'],
            u'film': [u'Pulp Fyction'],
            u'price': [u'15,00'],
            u'year': [u'1994']}],
 u'S363': [{u'director': [u'E. de Souza'],
            u'film': [u'Street Fighter'],
            u'price': [u'2,00'],
            u'year': [u'1994']}],
 u'T536': [{u'director': [u'Wachowski'],
            u'film': [u'The Matrix'],
            u'price': [u'19,00'],
            u'year': [u'1999']},
           {u'director': [u'Wachowski'],
            u'film': [u'The Matrix Reloaded'],
            u'price': [u'9,99'],
            u'year': [u'2003']},
           {u'director': [u'Wachowski'],
            u'film': [u'The Matrix'],
            u'price': [u'20,00'],
            u'year': [u'1999']}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it was a one off and I was in a hurry I would do it like this. Assuming for this example that your list of dictionaries is lod, and that the film title will only ever be a list with one item

```
new_dict = {k:[d for d in lod if d.get('film')[0] == k] for k in set(d.get('film')[0] for d in l)}
```

To make it more readable, and explain what it is doing, the same thing broken out, again the list of dictionaries is lod:

```
#get all the unique film names
# note: the [0] is because its a list for the title, and set doesn't work with lists,
#so we're just taking the first one for this example. 
films = set(d.get('film')[0] for d in lod)


#create a dictionary
new_dict = {}

#iterate over the unique film names
for k in films:
    #make a list of all the films that match the name we're on
    filmswiththisname = [d for d in lod if d.get('film')[0] == k]
    #add the list of films to the new dictionary with the film name as the key.
    new_dict[k] = filmswiththisname
```